# Accepting integers and ignoring non-integers from a file C#

Tags: c#

Currently I have written code that properly displays an error message if the text file contains ONLY non-integers

```
foreach (var line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(fileName))
  if (fileContents.Any(char.IsDigit))
  {
    return;
  }
    else
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Warning: File does not contain integers.");
    return;
  }
```

In addition, I have written code that converts a text file containing integers only from strings into ints

```
string[] eachString = fileContents.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int[] eachInt = new int[eachString.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < eachString.Length; i++)
   eachInt[i] = int.Parse(eachString[i]);
```

My current issue is trying to accept a file that has BOTH integers and non-integers BUT just completely ignore the non-integers and work only with the integers.

I thought by combining the two codes that I could achieve this, but apparently that is not so.

What would be a way to achieve this goal?

Comment: read each line, split the string, test each token if it is a int. TryParse... if it fails, its not an int...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

This snippet reads content from the file, splits contents with the specified delimiters and validates for number.

```
var onlyints = File.ReadLines(filename)
                .SelectMany(line => line.Split(new char[] {' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' ,','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                .Where(num => num => Regex.IsMatch(num, @"^\d+$"));
```

You can pop warning message when there are no number in the file like...

```
if(!onlyints.Any()) MessageBox.Show("Warning: File does not contain integers.");
```

Comment: where should I implement this at?

Comment: That's your say, you can completely replace your code with this snippet,  or you can tweak a bit if you would like to provide warning/error message in case there are no numbers in the file.

Comment: Okay. I am completely new to this language, so I am just not familiar with the statement you provided, but I am trying to learn as I go

Comment: Happens when we are learn new language, to understand what this statement all about I suggest go through this [article](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/linq/)

Answer (score 0):

One of the "old school" approaches before linq saved all our butts from this kind of thing. Uncompiled as I'm on mobile atm (doing code on a mobile is hard, just so you know).

```
private List<int> test()
{
    var intResults = new List<int>();
    var file = File.ReadLines("blah");
    foreach (var line in file)
    {
       var lineSplit = line.Split(
            new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

         foreach (var item in lineSplit)
         {
             var result = 0;
             if (int.TryParse(item, out result))
                 intResults.Add(result); 
         }
    }
    return intResults;
}
```

I don't expect this to be the answer as the linq option is much more elegant but it's just showing other ways of achieving the same goal :)

Edit: Method wasn't returning anything -_-